# How can i close the expanded menu when i click other menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

the menu has toggle menu but when i click other menu it wont close and stay opened. i need close expanded menu when i click other menu.`

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a data-toggle="collapse in" data-parent="#accordion" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1" aria-expanded="false">Link 2 (toggle)</a>
      <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1">
        <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2.3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
        }
    });
});
```